# Twig Form Blocks

Tags: symfony, themes, twig, block

I know that i can override checkbox_widget in my form_theme file like that

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
my Code
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

The problem is that I have all files loaded globally so in this way I would override all checkbox_widget in application. But i need to override checkbox in one form.
So the question is How i can override checkbox_widget for one specific form or override specific field widget somehow ?

I tried something like this but it doesn't works:

```
{% block MyFormName_checkbox_widget %}
my Code
{% endblock MyFormName_checkbox_widget %}
```

Comment: Make a new theme that extends (and overwrites) your original theme. Then use the extended theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use twig macros instead of blocks. Docs here: [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) and [import](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html).